# How can I use System.Security.Cryptography.ChaCha20Poly1305 on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, windows-10, .net-8.0

I am trying to use [`System.Security.Cryptography.ChaCha20Poly1305`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.chacha20poly1305) in C#. My platform and version information:

- Windows NT 10.0.19045.0
- .NET 8.0.3 (8.0.3)
- System.Security.Cryptography version: System.Security.Cryptography, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

But whenever I try to use this class to encrypt anything, I receive the following error:

**System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Algorithm 'ChaCha20Poly1305' is not supported on this platform.'**

Why does this not work?  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.chacha20poly1305?view=net-8.0) it appears my platform is supported.

This is my simplified test console app:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System;

namespace TestTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Environment version: {0} ({1}), {2}", System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription , Environment.Version, Environment.OSVersion);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} version: {1}", typeof(ChaCha20Poly1305).Namespace, typeof(ChaCha20Poly1305).Assembly.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine("ChaCha20Poly1305.IsSupported = {0}.\n", ChaCha20Poly1305.IsSupported);

            byte[] key = new byte[32];
            byte[] nonce = new byte[12];
            byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
            byte[] cipherText = new byte[plainText.Length];
            byte[] tag = new byte[16];
            using var chaChaPoly = new ChaCha20Poly1305(key);
            chaChaPoly.Encrypt(nonce, plainText, cipherText, tag);
            
            Console.WriteLine("Base64 cipherText: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText));
        }
    }
}
```

While this fails in my environment, it works on as a .NET Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qEURzH.

**Update**
[`ChaCha20Poly1305.IsSupported`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.chacha20poly1305.issupported?view=net-8.0) is returning false.  Why is this happening given that I am not using any of the documented unsupported platforms `[UnsupportedOSPlatform("browser")]`, `[UnsupportedOSPlatform("ios")]` or `[UnsupportedOSPlatform("tvos")]`?

Comment: What platform + implementation of `ChaCha20Poly1305` are you using?  If you are using [`System.Security.Cryptography.ChaCha20Poly1305`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.chacha20poly1305) did you check the [`IsSupported`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.chacha20poly1305.issupported) property?  The docs indicate the following unsupported platforms: `[UnsupportedOSPlatform("browser")]`, `[UnsupportedOSPlatform("ios")]` and `[UnsupportedOSPlatform("tvos")]`, are you running on one of those?

Comment: Alternatively you might instead be using [`NSec.Cryptography.AeadAlgorithm.ChaCha20Poly1305`](https://nsec.rocks/docs/api/nsec.cryptography.aeadalgorithm#chacha20poly1305) -- same name, different namespace + library.  Since we can't guess which, please [edit] your question to share a full [mcve] with complete code, framework + platform info that we could use to duplicate your problem, as suggested by [ask].  With that information your question should be answerable and could get reopened.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to run in a browser, or inside some sort of emulator?  Also, what .NET or .NET Core version are you using?

Comment: Your code seems to work on .NET 8.0.0 (8.0.0), Unix 6.2.0.1018, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/qEURzH.  The fact that you're using default values for the key and nonce seems insecure though.  (I am not a security professional though.)

Comment: My Environment version is .NET 8.0.3 (8.0.3), Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19045.0. Thanks a lot @dbc

Comment: You're welcome.  What are your values of `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription`, `Environment.Version`, `Environment.OSVersion` and `ChaCha20Poly1305.IsSupported`?  I updated my fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/qEURzH to show then, could you edit your test program to print them as well, and share the results?  The value of `typeof(ChaCha20Poly1305).Assembly.FullName` might also help.  Thanks!

Comment: Environment version: .NET 8.0.3 (8.0.3), Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19045.0
System.Security.Cryptography version: System.Security.Cryptography, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
ChaCha20Poly1305.IsSupported = False.

Comment: I think, I found the problem according to the microsoft website: ChaCha20Poly1305 is supported on Windows 10 Build 20142+ and Linux with OpenSSL 1.1.0+
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography)

Comment: I better found another way. thanks again @dbc

Comment: If you found a "better way" then please be so kind to share it. Others may be looking for a similar answer.